# Does there exist a linear equation system with a NAND-like behavior?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does there exist an equation system with only linear equalities and inequalities and exhibits a NAND-like behavior?
By 'NAND-like' I mean, among all the variables in the system there are 3 vars $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$, such that all solutions with $x_3 = 0$ imply $x_1 = x_2 = 1$, and all solutions with $x_3 = 1$ can be classified into 3 categories, with each category receiving at least 1 solution:

1. $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 0$
2. $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 1$
3. $x_1 = x_2 = 0$

Note: the converse does not need to be hold.

Comment: This question does not seem research level to me (see the FAQ). Besides, without context it's hard to guess why we should be bothered to solve this exercise or disprove the statement (no offense meant).

Comment: If $x_i$ are not integers I suppose you can't do this (probably it would imply P=NP).

Comment: All variables can be real numbers.

Comment: If all variables are real and all (in)equations are linear then the set described by the system is convex. Then surely the condition $x_3=0\Rightarrow x_1=x_2=1$ is impossible since the solution set will contain the whole segment $[(0,0,0) , (1,1,0) ]$.

Comment: It matters what kinds of system you allow.  You can't represent a nonconvex set by an intersection of half spaces.  If you allow unions, you can probably get away with the union of three or fewer such systems.

Comment: Spending a few minutes more thought suggests the following: represent the NAND truth table as 4 points in R^3. The tetrahedron with those 4 vertices should meet your criteria, and also be the intersection of four half spaces.  The four inequalities should be straightforward (one is x_3 <= 1), and I leave that to you.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

In a comment the OP wants $x_i$ reals.

In this case I believe this is impossible with a **linear system**
since almost sure it would imply $P=NP$.

In particular I believe one can't linearly encode $x_i \in \{0,1\}$
for $x_i$ real or rational.

---

**EDIT 2**

Due to discussion in comments, here is the explicit CNF:
$$
((x_1 \lor x_3) \land (x_2 \lor x_3) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3))
$$

**Original answer for integers**

If I understand correctly you want to work with variables $x_i \in \{0,1\}$
and the solutions of the system to be exactly the solutions to 
$x_3 := x_1 \; \rm{NAND} \; x_2 $

This is possible and one approach is first to convert
the formula to [Conjunctive Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_Normal_Form).

Then encode it to linear system:

Replace $\lnot x$ by $ 1-x$.

Encode each clause $ x_1 \lor x_2 \ldots \lor x_n$ as $ x_1 + x_2 \ldots +x_n  >0 $

(taking into account the negation).

You get a system of inequalities containing $x_i$ and $ 1 - x_j$.

Will try to make explicit system.

Comment: I assume $x_i$ are integers and one can trivially force them in {0,1}. If they are not integers probably it can't be done since it probably would imply P=NP.

Comment: Let's try again.  First constrain the (integer) variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$ to lie in $\{0,1\}$.  Let $y = x_1 + x_2$.  Then $x_1 \land x_2 \iff y \geq 2$.  So $x_1 \text{ NAND } x_2 \iff y < 2$.  So it would suffice to have indicator variables for inequalities.  I don't know how optimistic that is.

Comment: @BenBarber It is certainly possible, not sure if yours is entirely correct. In a comment the OP wants $x_i$ reals. I suppose this makes the answer negative.

Comment: @joro With integers only I'm not so sure if it is possible with a purely linear system (i.e. without nonlinear indicator functions and similar tools).

Comment: @Waldemar I am pretty sure, will try to make explicit solution. So you have the boolean OR,AND,NOT with inequalities and $1-$ which is certainly a basis.

Comment: @Waldemar note that your are allowed to use auxiliary variables $y_i$. Haven't thought if it is possible with only 3 variables.

Comment: @Waldemar edited the question giving explicit CNF.

Answer (score 1):

Try
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_3 & \leq & 1 \\
x_1 + x_3 & \geq & 1 \\
x_2 + x_3 & \geq & 1 \\
x_1 + x_2+ x_3 & \leq & 2. 
 \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I'm unsure about the categories part; you could use x_i > 1/2 or some related combination perhaps.